# I'm trying to add dynamic scripts into a page but its just showing as txt in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using JS to traverse XML to create elements on the DOM for a single page application, I now want to do the same to handle the logic of panel progression using jQuery.
Here is the Javascript;

```
    /* XML Script for Screen Output */
    var xmldata = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <script classes="" title="Example Script" brand1="" script1="">
    <agent brand="Genius PPT" name="Test User" status="Demonstration">
    </agent>
    <panels number="8">
    <panel classes="col-xs-3 blue" forFrame="scriptSection" initial="show" name="Panel1"></panel>
    <panel classes="col-xs-3 white" forFrame="scriptSection" initial="hide" name="Panel2"></panel>
    <panel classes="col-xs-3 blue" forFrame="scriptSection" initial="hide" name="Panel3"></panel>
    <panel classes="col-xs-3 white" forFrame="scriptSection" initial="hide" name="Panel4"></panel>
    <panel classes="col-xs-4 blue" forFrame="scriptSection" initial="hide" name="Panel5"></panel>
    <panel classes="col-xs-4 white" forFrame="scriptSection" initial="hide" name="Panel6"></panel>
    <panel classes="col-xs-4 blue" forFrame="scriptSection" initial="hide" name="Panel7"></panel>
    <panel classes="col-xs-12 white" forFrame="scriptSection" initial="hide" name="Panel8"></panel>
    </panels>
    <elements>
    // Buttons
        <Button classes="btn-default col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-2 callControl" forFrame="callControl" id="transferCall" name="Transfer call" state=" ">
        </Button>
        <Button classes="btn-default col-xs-2 callControl" forFrame="callControl" id="holdCall" name="Place Call on hold" state=" ">
        </Button>
        <Button classes="btn-default col-xs-2 callControl" forFrame="callControl" id="EndCall" name="End call" state="">
        </Button>
        <Button classes="btn-default col-xs-2 callControl" forFrame="callControl" id="MakeNewCall" name="Make New Call" state="disabled">
        </Button>
        <Button classes="btn-success col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-2" id="ScriptSubmit" forFrame="ScriptSelectRow4" name="Select Script" state="">
        </Button>
        <Button classes="col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-10" forFrame="ScriptSelectRow5" id="ToLogin" name="Back" state="">
        </Button>
        <End></End>
    </elements>
</script>`;
/* DOM Parsing*/
var parser0 = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser0.parseFromString(xmldata, "text/xml");
var tags =xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('*');
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i="0"; i <tags.length; i++){
        switch (tags[i].nodeName){
        case "panels":
            break;
        case "panel":
            addPanel(tags[i].getAttribute("classes"), tags[i].getAttribute("forFrame"), tags[i].getAttribute("initial"), tags[i].getAttribute("name"));
            break;

        }
    }
});
function addPanel(classes, forFrame, initial, name){
    var a = '<section class="'+ classes + '" id ="' + name + 'Panel"><h2 class="text-center">' + name + '</h2><p id="' + name + 'Row1"></p><p id="' + name + 'Row2"></p><p id="' + name + 'Row3"></p></section>';
    var b = '#' + forFrame;
    var c = 'start' + name + initial;
    var d = '<script id ="' + c + '"></script>';
    var e = 'function ' + c + '(){';
    var f = '$("' + name + 'Panel").' + initial + '();}';
    $(b).append(a);
    $(b).append(d);//fine
    $(d).append(e);//inside script
    $(d).append(f);//inside script
    $(d).append(c);//inside/script
 console.log(e + f + ' should be inside the script with id ' + d);
}
```

/* Hardcoded script to validate code correct */

Here is the html;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang=en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Logic Proof of concept with embedded XML</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <header class="row text-center">
    <h1>Example Page to prove Logic capability</h1>
    </header>
    <main class="row" id="scriptSection">
    </main>
    <footer class="row">
    <script src="javascript/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/logic.js"></script>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

On loading the page I get no console errors or warnings but so far have nanaged to get the functions to onto the page outside the script tags or with code above the function code vanishes.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong

Answer (score 1):

I have added the xml into an object and it behaves correctly
scriptXML = JSON.parse(message).XML; as it now comes in as part of a JSON response from the server.